# Proguard : Proguard.ParseException

Tags: android, proguard, obfuscation

I am trying to export my android application with proguard enabled when I get this error:-

```
 Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
 proguard.ParseException: Expecting java type before 'â€‚' in line 79 of file 'C:\Documents and Settings\Acer.ACER-2487AA0235\My Documents\Eclipse\Myproject\proguard-project.txt',
included from argument number 4
at proguard.ConfigurationParser.checkJavaIdentifier(ConfigurationParser.java:1187)
at proguard.ConfigurationParser.parseMemberSpecificationArguments(ConfigurationParser.java:842)
at proguard.ConfigurationParser.parseClassSpecificationArguments(ConfigurationParser.java:697)
at proguard.ConfigurationParser.parseKeepClassSpecificationArguments(ConfigurationParser.java:490)
at proguard.ConfigurationParser.parse(ConfigurationParser.java:139)
at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:484)
```

**Lines 77-80 from proguard-project.txt:-**

```
-keepclassmembers class * 
{ 
 @android.webkit.JavascriptInterface <methods>;
}
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Proguard Error Code 1: Proguard.ParseException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27074801/proguard-error-code-1-proguard-parseexception)

Answer (score 0):

```
-keepattributes JavascriptInterface
-keepclassmembers class * {
    @android.webkit.JavascriptInterface <methods>;
}
```

Comment: Again, your answer would benefit from adding some details.